# In My XML i'm getting error as "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. "

Tags: dtd, xml

i've written an xslt for converting an xml file into a html file which is working as expected if i takeout the DTD part(commenting it out).

Below is my DTD. can you please tell me why am i getting this error and how do i rectify it and how to use my DTD without errors in my xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ===================================================================

     Name:           SMGHK DTD
     Project:         SMGHK

     Purpose:       A generic DTD for SMGHK Books.

     =================================================================== -->
<!-- ======================================================================= -->
<!--                       Character Entities                                -->
<!-- ======================================================================= -->
<!ENTITY % ISOamsa PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Math Symbols: Arrow Relations//EN//XML" "isoamsa.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOamsb PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Math Symbols: Binary Operators//EN//XML" "isoamsb.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOamsc PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Math Symbols: Delimiters//EN//XML" "isoamsc.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOamsn PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Math Symbols: Negated Relations//EN//XML" "isoamsn.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOamso PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Math Symbols: Ordinary//EN//XML" "isoamso.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOamsr PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Math Symbols: Relations//EN//XML" "isoamsr.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISObox PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Math Symbols: Relations//EN//XML" "isobox.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOcyr1 PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Russian Cyrillic//EN//XML" "isocyr1.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOcyr2 PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Non-Russian Cyrillic//EN//XML" "isocyr2.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOdia PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Non-Russian Cyrillic//EN//XML" "isodia.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOgrk1 PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Greek Letters//EN//XML" "isogrk1.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOgrk2 PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Monotoniko Greek//EN//XML" "isogrk2.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOgrk3 PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Greek Symbols//EN//XML" "isogrk3.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOgrk4 PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Alternative Greek Symbols//EN//XML" "isogrk4.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOlat1 PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Latin 1//EN//XML" "isolat1.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOlat2 PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Latin 2//EN//XML" "isolat2.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOnum PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Numeric and Special Graphic//EN//XML" "isonum.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOpub PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Publishing//EN//XML" "isopub.ent">
<!ENTITY % ISOtech PUBLIC "ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES General Technical//EN//XML" "isotech.ent">
%ISOamsa;%ISOamsb;%ISOamsc;%ISOamsn;%ISOamso;%ISOamsr;%ISObox;%ISOcyr1;%ISOcyr2;%ISOdia;%ISOgrk1;%ISOgrk2;%ISOgrk3;%ISOgrk4;%ISOlat1;%ISOlat2;%ISOnum;%ISOpub;%ISOtech;
<!-- ============================================================ -->
<!--                    ENTITY DEFINITIONS  -->
<!-- ============================================================ -->
<!ENTITY % form.elements SYSTEM
           "forms.ent">
<!ENTITY % table.elements SYSTEM
           "table.ent">
<!ENTITY % common.attrib " id
              ID
              #IMPLIED
       differentiation (grey | head | box | footnote) #IMPLIED
    columns CDATA #IMPLIED
    update-date CDATA #IMPLIED
    num CDATA #IMPLIED
         ">
<!ENTITY % block.elements "para | orderedlist | itemizedlist | unorderedlist | checklist | table | figure |
             simplelist | note | extract | box | maths | page">
<!-- "footnoteref", "footnote" and "ref" elements have been added to %inline.base on 06/21/2006 -->
<!ENTITY % inline.base "#PCDATA | endnoteref | xref | glossterm | endnote | phrase | quote | indexterm | content-style | footnoteref | footnote | ref | uri | case | casename | legal | break | page | c">
<!ENTITY % inline.elements "name | email | author | authorinitials | inlinegraphic | address | publishername | fib | page">
<!ENTITY % book-meta-model "product-number?, wms-number?, subject*, filing-instructions?, blurb?">
<!ENTITY % chapter-meta-model "author*, copyright?, pub-date?, subject*, contributor*, source*, rev-date?">
<!ENTITY % graphic-meta-model "text">
<!ENTITY % combined "endnoteref | xref | glossterm | endnote | phrase | quote | indexterm | content-style | footnoteref | footnote | ref | uri | case | casename | legal | name | email | author | authorinitials | inlinegraphic | address | publishername | fib | para | orderedlist | unorderedlist | itemizedlist | checklist | table | figure |
             simplelist | note | extract | box | break | page">
<!ENTITY % math-model "title?, subtitle?, equation+,
                         (para)*">
<!-- ============================================================ -->
<!--                    BOOK ELEMENTS  -->
<!-- ============================================================ -->
<!ELEMENT book ((page?, title, subtitle?), book-meta?, frontmatter, body, backmatter?)>
<!ATTLIST book
%common.attrib; 
pubid CDATA #IMPLIED
label CDATA #IMPLIED
type (chb | tre) #REQUIRED
interest-code CDATA #IMPLIED
interest-description CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT book-meta (%book-meta-model;)>
<!ELEMENT frontmatter (page | figure | seriesinfo | bookinfo | journalinfo | toc | glossary | chapter | part)*>
<!ELEMENT body (chapter | part | page)*>
<!ELEMENT backmatter (glossary | bibliography | chapter | part | appendix | toa | index | page)*>
<!-- "title" and "edition" elements have been added to "bookinfo" element on 06/22/2006 -->
<!ELEMENT bookinfo (title?, (authors? | editor? | contribution? | graphic? | publisherinfo? | copyright? | contactinfo? | legalnotice? | catalogrecord? | isbn? | printinfo? | edition? | otherinfo | page)*)>
<!ATTLIST bookinfo
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT journalinfo (journtitlepage?, journinfopage?)>
<!ATTLIST journalinfo
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT journtitlepage (title?, subtitle?, (volume? | issue? | issuedate?)*)>
<!ATTLIST journtitlepage
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT volume (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST volume
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT issue (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST issue
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT issuedate (day | month | year)*>
<!ATTLIST issuedate
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT journinfopage (title?, (authors? | editors? | editorial? | contribution? | graphic? | publisherinfo? | copyright? | contactinfo? | legalnotice? | catalogrecord? | issn? | printinfo? | otherinfo)*)>
<!ATTLIST journinfopage
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT editors (para? | editor)+>
<!ATTLIST editors
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT editorial (title?, editors)>
<!ATTLIST editorial
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT seriesinfo ((page?, title, subtitle?)?, editor?, issn?, pubhistory, (%block.elements;)*)>
<!ATTLIST seriesinfo
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT printinfo (%block.elements;)*>
<!ATTLIST printinfo
%common.attrib; 
>
<!-- "edition" element has been created on 06/21/2006 -->
<!ELEMENT edition (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST edition
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT publisherinfo (para+)>
<!ATTLIST publisherinfo
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT pubtitle (#PCDATA | endnoteref | xref | glossterm | endnote | phrase | quote | indexterm | content-style | footnoteref | footnote | ref | uri | case | casename | legal | break | name | email | author | authorinitials | inlinegraphic | address | publishername | fib | page)*>
<!ATTLIST pubtitle
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT issn (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST issn
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT publishername (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST publishername
%common.attrib; 
>
<!-- "title" element has been added to "pubhistory" element on 06/24/2006 -->
<!ELEMENT pubhistory (title?, (para? | publist)*)>
<!ATTLIST pubhistory
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT publist (publication)+>
<!ATTLIST publist
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT legalnotice (%block.elements;)+>
<!ATTLIST legalnotice
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT copyright (para)+>
<!ATTLIST copyright
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT otherinfo (title?, (%block.elements;)*)>
<!ATTLIST otherinfo
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT catalogrecord (catalog)+>
<!ATTLIST catalogrecord
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT catalog (address, para)+>
<!ATTLIST catalog
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT publication (#PCDATA | pubtitle | author | edition)*>
<!ATTLIST publication
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST isbn
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT editor (type?, (address? | name)*, affiliation?)>
<!ATTLIST editor
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT type (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST type
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT affiliation (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST affiliation
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT contribution (label, contributor+)>
<!ATTLIST contribution
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT label (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST label
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT contributor (role, name)+>
<!ATTLIST contributor
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT role (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST role
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT case (#PCDATA | casename | content-style | break)*>
<!ATTLIST case
%common.attrib; 
type (reply | versus) #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT casename (#PCDATA | content-style | break | pgs | page)*>
<!ATTLIST casename
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT legal (#PCDATA | l-title | l-num | l-name | l-date | l-item | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST legal
%common.attrib; 
type (USC | IRC | Pub-L | Statute | CFR | Secur-Act | Secur-Rel | Exch-Act | Exch-Rel | Exch-Rule | Regul | St-Code | Unif-Act | Rest | Fed-App | Fed-Bankr | Fed-Civ) #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT l-title (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST l-title
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT l-num (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST l-num
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT l-name (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST l-name
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT l-date (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST l-date
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT l-item (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST l-item
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA | honorific | firstname | middlename | surname)*>
<!ATTLIST name
%common.attrib; 
>
<!-- "orgname" element has been created on 06/21/2006 -->
<!ELEMENT orgname (#PCDATA | footnoteref | footnote)*>
<!ATTLIST orgname
%common.attrib; 
>
<!-- "title" element has been added to "contactinfo" element on 06/22/2006 -->
<!ELEMENT contactinfo (title?, para+)>
<!ATTLIST contactinfo
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT authors (author)+>
<!ATTLIST authors
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT toc (page | title | subtitle | toc-frontitem | toc-part | toc-backitem)*>
<!ATTLIST toc
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT toc-frontitem (toc-title, toc-pg?, otherinfo*, author*)>
<!ATTLIST toc-frontitem
%common.attrib; 
num CDATA #IMPLIED
linkend IDREF #IMPLIED
endterm CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT toc-backitem (toc-title, toc-pg?, otherinfo*, author*)>
<!ATTLIST toc-backitem
%common.attrib; 
num CDATA #IMPLIED
linkend IDREF #IMPLIED
endterm CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT toc-part (title?, subtitle?, (toc-div | page)*)>
<!ATTLIST toc-part
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT toc-div (title?, subtitle?, (toc-item | page)*)>
<!ATTLIST toc-div
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT toc-item (toc-title?, toc-pg?, otherinfo*, author*, (toc-subitem | page)*)>
<!ATTLIST toc-item
%common.attrib; 
num CDATA #IMPLIED
linkend IDREF #IMPLIED
endterm CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT toc-subitem (toc-title, toc-pg?, otherinfo*, author*, (toc-subitem | page)*)>
<!ATTLIST toc-subitem
%common.attrib; 
num CDATA #IMPLIED
linkend IDREF #IMPLIED
endterm CDATA #IMPLIED
level (1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6) #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT toc-title (#PCDATA | content-style | xref | c)*>
<!ATTLIST toc-title
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT toc-pg (#PCDATA | content-style | xref)*>
<!ATTLIST toc-pg
%common.attrib; 
>
<!-- TABLE OF AUTHORITIES (LIST OF CASES) -->
<!ELEMENT toa (pgs | title | subtitle | para | toa-section | page)*>
<!ATTLIST toa
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT toa-section (title | subtitle | toa-div | page)*>
<!ATTLIST toa-section
%common.attrib; 
type CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT toa-div (pgs | title | subtitle | toa-div | toa-entry | page)*>
<!ATTLIST toa-div
%common.attrib; 
level (div1 | div2 | div3 | div4 | div5) #REQUIRED
>
<!--ELEMENT toa-entry (primary-entry+, (secondary-entry | tertiary-entry)*)-->
<!ELEMENT toa-entry (primary-entry)>
<!ATTLIST toa-entry
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT primary-entry (entry-name, pgs?, secondary-entry*)>
<!ATTLIST primary-entry
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT secondary-entry (entry-name, pgs?, tertiary-entry*)>
<!ATTLIST secondary-entry
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT tertiary-entry (entry-name, pgs?)>
<!ATTLIST tertiary-entry
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT entry-name (#PCDATA | xref | content-style | unorderedlist | extract)*>
<!ATTLIST entry-name
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT pgs (#PCDATA | pg)*>
<!ATTLIST pgs
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT pg (#PCDATA | xref | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST pg
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT chapter (title | subtitle | chapter-meta | biography | toc | introduction | %block.elements; | forms | section | endnotes | bibliography | qandaset | appendix | exhibits | exhibit | letter | toa)*>
<!-- "aboutauthor" and "abbreviations" attribute values have been added to "type" attribute on 06/22/2006 -->
<!ATTLIST chapter
%common.attrib; 
type (cdinfo | acknowledgement | glossary | dedication | preface | aboutauthor | abbreviations | tabchap) #IMPLIED
level CDATA #IMPLIED
num CDATA #IMPLIED
interest-code CDATA #IMPLIED
interest-description CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT chapter-meta (%chapter-meta-model;)>
<!ELEMENT glossary ((title, subtitle?)?, (%block.elements;)*, (glossdiv? | glossentry+))>
<!ATTLIST glossary
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT biography ((title, subtitle?)?, (%block.elements;)*)>
<!ELEMENT bibliography ((title, subtitle?)?, (%block.elements;)*, (bibliodiv? | biblioentry+))>
<!ATTLIST bibliography
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT bibliodiv ((title, subtitle?)?, (%block.elements;)*, (biblioentry)+)>
<!ATTLIST bibliodiv
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT biblioentry (#PCDATA | endnoteref | xref | glossterm | endnote | phrase | quote | indexterm | content-style | name | email | author | authorinitials | inlinegraphic | address | publishername | fib | title | subtitle | citetitle | date | publisher | pagenums | uri | edition | volume | issue | page)*>
<!ATTLIST biblioentry
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT citetitle (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT date (day | month | year)*>
<!ELEMENT blank-date (para)>
<!ELEMENT pub-date (day | month | year)*>
<!ELEMENT rev-date (day | month | year)*>
<!ELEMENT day (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT month (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher (publishername, address*)>
<!ELEMENT pagenums (#PCDATA)>
<!-- "uri" element has been created on 06/22/2006 -->
<!ELEMENT uri (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST uri
%common.attrib; 
href CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT glossdiv ((title, subtitle?)?, (%block.elements;)*, (glossentry)+)>
<!ATTLIST glossdiv
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT glossentry (glossterm, (indexterm)*, (glosssee | glossdef+))>
<!ATTLIST glossentry
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT glossterm (#PCDATA | endnoteref | xref | glossterm | endnote | phrase | quote | indexterm | content-style | footnoteref | footnote | ref | uri | case | casename | legal | break | name | email | author | authorinitials | inlinegraphic | address | publishername | fib | page)*>
<!ATTLIST glossterm
%common.attrib; 
linkend IDREF #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT glosssee (#PCDATA | endnoteref | xref | glossterm | endnote | phrase | quote | indexterm | content-style | footnoteref | footnote | ref | uri | case | casename | legal | break | name | email | author | authorinitials | inlinegraphic | address | publishername | fib | page)*>
<!ATTLIST glosssee
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT glossseealso (#PCDATA | endnoteref | xref | glossterm | endnote | phrase | quote | indexterm | content-style | footnoteref | footnote | ref | uri | case | casename | legal | break | name | email | author | authorinitials | inlinegraphic | address | publishername | fib | page)*>
<!ATTLIST glossseealso
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT glossdef ((%block.elements;)+, glossseealso*)>
<!ATTLIST glossdef
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT appendix (page?, title, subtitle?, (toc | %block.elements; | forms | section | exhibits | exhibit)*)>
<!ATTLIST appendix
     num CDATA #IMPLIED
     differentiation CDATA #IMPLIED
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT index (title | subtitle | indexdiv | page)+>
<!ATTLIST index
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT indexdiv (title, (indexentry | page)+)>
<!ATTLIST indexdiv
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT indexentry (primaryie+, (secondaryie | tertiaryie | page)*)>
<!ATTLIST indexentry
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT primaryie (#PCDATA | content-style | xref)*>
<!ATTLIST primaryie
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT secondaryie (#PCDATA | content-style | xref)*>
<!ATTLIST secondaryie
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT tertiaryie (#PCDATA | content-style | xref)*>
<!ATTLIST tertiaryie
%common.attrib; 
level (1 | 2 | 3 | 4) #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT part ((title, subtitle?), (appendix | chapter | toc | index | glossary | bibliography | page)+)>
<!ATTLIST part
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT section (title, subtitle?, (%block.elements; | forms | section)*)>
<!ATTLIST section
%common.attrib; 
type CDATA #IMPLIED
level (sect1 | sect2 | sect3 | sect4 | sect5 | sect6 | sect7 | sect8 | sect9 | sect10) #IMPLIED
number-type (arabic | lower.alpha | upper.alpha | lower.roman | upper.roman | manual | unnumbered) #IMPLIED
num CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT box (title?, subtitle?, (%block.elements; | forms)*, (section)*)>
<!ATTLIST box
%common.attrib; 
border (border | none) "border"
>
<!ELEMENT subject (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT source (para)*>
<!ELEMENT exhibits (exhibit+)>
<!ELEMENT exhibit (page?, exhibit-meta, blank-date?, head1?, head2?, (endorsement | policy | schedule | letter | other | page)*)>
<!ATTLIST exhibit
%common.attrib; 
type CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT exhibit-meta (form-num?, title, subtitle?)>
<!ATTLIST exhibit-meta
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT form-num (%inline.base;)*>
<!ELEMENT head1 (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT head2 (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT head3 (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT endorsement ((title? | head1? | head2?)*, (figure | form | page)+)>
<!ATTLIST endorsement
%common.attrib; 
type CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT letter (head1?, head2?, head3?, (to | via | subject | date | letter-info | %block.elements; | section)*, from?, (form)*)>
<!ATTLIST letter
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT to (%combined;)*>
<!ATTLIST to
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT via (%combined;)*>
<!ATTLIST via
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT from (%combined;)*>
<!ATTLIST from
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT letter-info (%combined;)*>
<!ATTLIST letter-info
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT schedule ((title? | head1?)*, (figure | form | page)+)>
<!ATTLIST schedule
%common.attrib; 
type CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT policy ((title? | head1? | head2?)*, (figure | form | page)+)>
<!ATTLIST policy
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT other ((title? | head1? | head2?)*, (figure | form | page)+)>
<!ATTLIST other
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT product-number (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST product-number
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT wms-number (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST wms-number
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT filing-instructions ((title? | edition? | subtitle?)*, (%block.elements;)*)>
<!ATTLIST filing-instructions
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT blurb (title | edition | authors | %block.elements;)*>
<!ATTLIST blurb
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT photo-credit (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST photo-credit
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT introduction ((title, subtitle?)?, (%block.elements; | forms)*)>
<!ATTLIST introduction
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT endnotes EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST endnotes
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT text (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST text
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT maths (%math-model;)>
<!ATTLIST maths
%common.attrib; 
position (fixed | float | margin) #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT equation (para | figure)*>
<!ATTLIST equation
%common.attrib; 
number (numbered | nonumber) #IMPLIED
eqn-num CDATA #IMPLIED
href CDATA #IMPLIED
display (inline | block) #REQUIRED
width CDATA #IMPLIED
height CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT break (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST break
%common.attrib; 
>
<!ELEMENT page (#PCDATA | content-style)*>
<!ATTLIST page
num CDATA #IMPLIED
>

<!-- ============================================================ -->
<!--                    BLOCK ELEMENTS  -->
<!-- ============================================================ -->
%form.elements;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say for sure why you are getting an error message, because in your question you don't quote the error message and you don't tell what processor you are invoking or how.  So any answers you get will necessarily be guesswork based on insufficient evidence.

The document you show uses DTD syntax.  It's not an XML document and it should not begin with an XML declaration.  From your description it sounds as if you are asking an XML parser to parse it as an XML document; don't do that.